# Parse, bringing all results

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to make a highscores list and I could make it for local database by realm. And now, I am trying to do this with parse server for global high scores. In realm I could do this by like this and I could not be succesful on parse. How can I make it on parse like I did on realm. I just needed to throw all scores to parse database and then sort and take first 10.

```
private void addNewHighScoreToLocalDatabase(final int score) {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            LocalHighScore localHighScore = realm.createObject(LocalHighScore.class);
            localHighScore.setScore(score);
        }
    });
}

RealmResults<LocalHighScore> results = realm.where(LocalHighScore.class).sort("score", Sort.DESCENDING).findAll();
    int count = results.size();
    TextView[] order = {first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eight, ninth, tenth};
    for (int i = 0; order.length > i; i++) {
        order[i].setText(results.get(i).getScore() + "");
    }



ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GlobalHighScore");
    query.setLimit(10).orderByDescending("score");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                for (int i = 0; orderScore.length > i; i++) {
                    orderScore[i].setText(objects.get(i).getString("score")+"");
                    orderName[i].setText(objects.get(i).getString("name")+"");
            }
        }
    });
```

I am trying to make this quer, but it returns empty list. I checked when adding element to database and it adds without bearing any problem.

Comment: Are your "local high scores" stored in separate classes from each other? Or do you have like, high score objects with a locale field?

Comment: I have GlobalHighScores class which holds score, name and ID for a user. I made a query but cannot get them like I am getting from a arraylist I can get only the first result.

Comment: You're iterating over the length of orderScore, rather than your results. Since you set a limit of 10, objects should only have up to 10 objects, but it may have less.  So, I believe your issue is that orderScore isn't long enough.  However, if it was, you could run into another issue where you don't get 10 results back. You should iterate over the length of the objects array instead.  Are you sure that objects doesn't contain 10 items?

Answer (score 0):

Parse does this pretty simply with queries!

Here are the relevant methods you'll be using on your query:

[setLimit(int)](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#setLimit(int))
[orderByDescending(java.lang.String)](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#orderByDescending(java.lang.String))

Note that this works if you are storing all of your scores / high scores in a single class.  Say you have a`HighScore` class, you just need to set the limit to 10 and pass the key name for your scores.  You could add a `locale` field to your `HighScore`, so when you want to get your local high scores, you just add a [whereEqualTo](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) call to match the locale of the current user.

If you have separate classes for each locale (not recommended), to get your global high scores you will need to perform the query above with the limit of ten on every class, stitch together all the results, then sort locally. I'd really recommend going with the single high score class, though.